# Combo lenses and prisms for sums of products?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

If I have a record type, I can do pretty much anything I want to it with lenses. If I have a sum type, I can do pretty much whatever I want to it with prisms. But if I have a sum that includes a record, `makeFields` doesn't give me lenses into the fields (of course), but only traversals for them. `declarePrisms` seems a bit more promising. According to the documentation,

```
declarePrisms [d|
  data Exp = Lit Int | Var String | Lambda{ bound::String, body::Exp }
  |]
```

will create

```
data Exp = Lit Int | Var String | Lambda { bound::String, body::Exp }
_Lit :: Prism' Exp Int
_Var :: Prism' Exp String
_Lambda :: Prism' Exp (String, Exp)
```

This gets me almost there, but what I really want is more like this:

```
data Exp = Lit Int | Var String | Lambda String Exp
data LambdaRec = { _bound::String, _body::Exp }
...
_Lambda :: Prism' Exp LambdaRec
-- bound and body lenses into LambdaRec,
-- and ideally also traversals to look at them in Exp.
class MightBeLambda t where
  type BoundOptic t
  type BodyOptic t
  bound :: BoundOptic t
  body :: BodyOptic t
instance MightBeLambda Exp where
  type BoundOptic Exp = Traversal' Exp String
  ...
instance MightBeLambda LambdaRec where
  type BoundOptic LambdaRec = Lens' LambdaRec String
```

Is there any way to do something like this automatically, or would I have to do it by hand?

---

An even crazier way one might wish to do it:

```
data ExpTag = LitT | VarT | LambdaT

data Exp' :: ExpTag -> * where
  Lit' :: Int -> Exp' LitT
  Var' :: String -> Exp' VarT
  Lambda' :: { _bound::String, _body::Exp } -> Exp' LambdaT
```

Then the prisms can be defined evilly, using `unsafeCoerce` to avoid any risk of copying records.

Comment: Of course, the problem vanishes if you just stick to using `data` for _either_ sum or variant types but not both at once, i.e. `data Exp = Lit Int | Var String | Lambda LambdaRec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a detour through another generated Iso to get this behavior. (makePrisms generates Isos when applied to a type with a single constructor)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Demo where

import Control.Lens

data Exp = Lit Int | Var String | Lambda String Exp
data LambdaRec = LambdaRec { _bound::String, _body::Exp }

makePrisms ''Exp
makePrisms ''LambdaRec
makeLenses ''LambdaRec

_ExpLambdaRec :: Prism' Exp LambdaRec
_ExpLambdaRec = _Lambda . from _LambdaRec

-- Example using _ExpLambdaRec
expBound :: Traversal' Exp String
expBound = _ExpLambdaRec . bound
```

Note that thanks to optimizations that GHC can do that this intermediate record type isn't necessarily used in the generated code.

```
getBound :: Exp -> Maybe String
getBound = preview expBound

-- Generated core for getBound
--
-- getBound1 =
--   \ eta_B1 ->
--     case eta_B1 of _ {
--       __DEFAULT -> (Nothing) `cast` ...;
--       Lambda y1_a6XB y2_a6XC -> (Just y1_a6XB) `cast` ...
--     }
```