# Haskell: automatic creation of constuctor-checker / selector functions

Tags: haskell

In haskell, there's a common idiom for ADTs such as:

```
data MyData a = X a | Y a | Z a
```

...to define functions:

```
isX (X _) = True
isX _     = False

isY (Y _) = True
isY _     = False

isZ (Z _) = True
isZ _     = False
```

Is there any way to automatically generate these functions?

Motivation: This is arguably idiomatic, or not idiomatic haskell depending on who you ask... The standard library itself has `isJust`, `isNothing`.

Expanding the scope of the question, the record syntax allows you to create functions for a data type:

```
data MyData = A { a1 :: Type1, a2 :: Type2 } | B { b1 :: Type3, b2 :: Type4 }
```

And these functions have the types:

```
a1 :: MyData -> Type1
a2 :: MyData -> Type2
b1 :: MyData -> Type3
b2 :: MyData -> Type4
```

While this is undoubtedly great for data types with only 1 constructors, it is less so for data types with more than 1 constructor as the auto-generated functions result in errors when the wrong constructor has been used.

Is there any way to autogenerate functions with these types instead?

```
a1 :: MyData -> Maybe Type1
a2 :: MyData -> Maybe Type2
b1 :: MyData -> Maybe Type3
b2 :: MyData -> Maybe Type4
```

Comment: Why do you want such functions? IMO that's unidiomatic. _Boolean blindness_. Directly matching on the constructors where you need them, that's the Haskell way.

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is TemplateHaskell (well...) - but I agree with @leftaroundabout

Comment: This is your statutory warning that, as ADT stands both for "Algebraic Data Type" and "Abstract Data Type", it is an acronym well worth avoiding. Meanwhile, checkers and selectors are symptomatic of treating the former as if they are the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've expanded upon my question a bit...

Comment: I disagree with the comments above: these functions are totally OK, especially the selectors ones. Avoiding "boolean blindness" when you don't need to is an anti-anti-pattern (see [this](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/#comment-59)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is a bad idea.  It leads to error-prone code.  However, there is a better way that also includes this mechanism and positively answers your question.  Use [Prisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html).  You can [automatically derive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#g:3) them with Template Haskell.  Then you can use [`is`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Extras.html#v:is) to get what you want, but, you still shouldn't in the normal case.  Nevertheless, by providing prisms, your users can use better approaches while still having access to `is` when it is more convenient.

The end result is code like

```
data MyData a = X a | Y a | Z a
makePrisms ''MyData

filterX = filter (is _X)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful! I've expanded upon my question a bit... I'd much appreciate it if you could address that as well.

Comment: See [this unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732588/combo-lenses-and-prisms-for-sums-of-products) for a bit of discussion about this. You can get most of the way immediately using [declarePrisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#g:7) which you can compose with some tuple lenses to get traversals from which you can get the functions you want via [`^?`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-).

Comment: I'm not aware of a library that will give you exactly what you want, but you can always write the Template Haskell yourself.  In the context of the above, you'd want to produce [Traversals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html).  That would amount to making functions like `a1 f (A x y) = A <$> f x <*> pure y; a1 f (B x y) = pure (B x y)` or, only getting the read-only case of a [Fold](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#g:3), `a1 = folding (\t -> case t of A x _ -> Just x; _ -> Nothing)` and so forth.